# Roster for Pickleball Tournament

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to create a program that can generate Round Robin Pickleball rosters for $5$ to $16$ players on $1$ or two courts. Round Robin means that each player plays with every other player. Pickleball is like tennis with two players on each side.
I need to apply some limitations. Each player plays with every other player only once. Each player plays opposite every other player exactly twice where possible or at least once and no more than three times. Another limitation is that every player plays the least amount of games in a row. I have been successful with the smaller numbers by searching all combinations, but have not found great solutions for the higher number of players. The current program is available at BusyBrainConsulting.com for free. I have used the Combination Equation to create the pairs and a varying number of seeds to fill in all of the rounds. Some player numbers have an empty field as part of the last round to not violate the rules. I believe the following equations are valid, but don't know how to implement them other than the pair combinations:

For Pairs Combinations ($n$=Players, $r=2$): c=n!/(r!*(n-r)!)=n*(n-1)/2

For 1 Court Combinations ($c$=Pairs, $r=2$): 1c=c!/(r!*(c-r)!)=c*(c-1)/2

For 1 Court Solutions (Valid Combinations) (n=Players, r=4): n!/(r!*(n-r)!)*((r-1)!/(2^1)) //No Player in more than 1 place at a time

For 2 Court Combinations (1s=1 Court Solutions, r=2): 2c=1s!/(r!*(1s-r)!)=1s*(1s-1)/2
For 2 Court Solutions (Valid Combinations) (n=Players, r=8): n!/(r!*(n-r)!)*((r-1)!/(2^4)) //No Player in more than 1 place at a time

I may be going down the wrong path and any help would be greatly appreciated. The combinations for $16$ players and two courts is very large!

Comment: Use '\frac{a}{b}' when creating fractions $\frac{a}{b}$. They make your question more readable, consider adding some indentation as well